# Why SFML position is float?

Tags: c++, sfml

On SFML documentation I see that position of Sprites and shapes is... `float`. Why? Is it linked with `sf::View`, which bounds are `float` too?

Links to documentation:

[`sf::Transformable`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.0/classsf_1_1Transformable.php)

[`sf::View`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.0/classsf_1_1View.php)

[`sf::RenderWindow`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.0/classsf_1_1RenderWindow.php)

Comment: Why not? ------

Comment: RenderWindow size is uint, so I'm little bit confused now.

Comment: @Quentin because we (at least me and OP) cannot see the advantage of it, but can spot several disadvantages, like worse arithmetic performance and such. Mind then explaining why it's a floating point instead of an integer?

Comment: Using float allows for sub-pixel rendering, so lines don't need to snap to the pixel grid. This is useful for e.g. smooth animations.

Comment: GPU's are heavily optimized for work with floating point numbers which is why OpenGL (upon which SFML is built) works with floats.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog so should I depend on floats in every code on my application? How to handle in.e. mouse cursor events when cursor position is int, but all positions are float?

Comment: Most operating systems don't allow for fractional mouse coordinates, but that doesn't mean sub-pixel rendering cannot be done.

Comment: You can convert `int`s to `float`s losslessly in the range of pixel co-ordinates. You can truncate or round back again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need floating points in order to animate you sprites correctly. Imagine a position at x=1, and you increase the position based on your delta time to 1.1. It would take 10 frames to move your sprite to x=2 (next pixel). Using integers x would be rounded to 1, and you won't move at all.

Besides that, in order to render stuff, you have to calculate the transform matrix (using floats), so you had to convert to floats sooner or later anyways. This is how graphics API's work internally, SFML simply wraps everything up so you only have to worry with screen coordinates (pixels, in that case).

Comment: dan, your example is as simple as imagined me way to solve all of my problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Coordinates in SFML are floating point numbers rather than integers, because the actual transformation – from world coordinates to pixels on screen – doesn't have to happen in a 1:1 manner.

How you want to handle coordinates and their mapping is completely up to you.

For example, you might want to use floating point coordinates in a way that the integer portion identifies tile coordinates in a tile map, while the fractions represent the space between tile borders. In some other situation, you might want to map coordinates 1:1 to pixels.

In the end the `sf::View` in combination with the used `sf::RenderTarget` determine how coordinates are interpreted and what they actually mean:

```
sf::RenderWindow window({512, 512}, "Test Window");

// This view is basically the default view for the window above.
// It maps coordinates 1:1 to pixels, which means a position (25,50) would map to the pixel at (25,50).
// This is the most common way.
sf::View pixelSpace({256, 256}, {512, 512});

// This view only shows things between (0, 0) and (1, 1), similar to how texture coordinates are usually handled.
// This can be useful, for example if you want to visualize the UV mapping of a model.
// You set this view and then just render based on the texture coordinate.
sf::View uvSpace({.5f, .5f}, {1, 1});

// This is an example for a tile based game, where the view allows you to
// make something 1.0 wide and high and it will automatically be the size of one tile.
// In this example I assume a 16:10 display ratio and I want 16x10 tiles to show.
sf::View tileSpace({8, 5}, {16, 10});
```